# Can't access member second of std::pair

Tags: c++

I figured out how to store data in my `vector<vector<pair<int, int> > > v[1001];` doing it like this:

```
f >> x >> y; v[i][j].push_back(make_pair(x, y));
```

but I don't know how to access that data since it gives me the error:

> c++ - error: '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits > >::value_type' has no member named 'second''|

at this line:

```
c[j] = c[j + 1] * (v[foo][j].second - v[foo][j].first + 1);
```

`c[j]` being a simple array `int c[1001];`.
My question is: What I'am doing wrong?

Comment: `v[foo][j] is a vector`. You need one more index, like `v[foo][j][bar].second`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

v is an array of vector of vector of pair.  You need *three* indices:

```
    v[foo][j][???].first
```

Three indices is (almost always) too many.  You need to encapsulate in some sort of structure.

Comment: Correct, first [] relates to the array and the following two, to the nested vectors. The compiler simply tells you it cannot read `second` on a `vector<pair<int, int>>`